# LINQ extension method help sought II

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

Is there a way to make the parameters of this extension method 'intellisensible' from my view?

At the moment, I can get a tooltip nudge of what the parameters (in the controller action method) are but would love to confidently IntelliSense type the parameter names for 'safety'. Anyway, without further ado, the method, followed by the usage:

```
public static string Script<T>(this HtmlHelper html,
                                Expression<Action<T>> action) where T:Controller
{
    var call = action.Body as MethodCallExpression;

    if (call != null)
    {
        // paramDic - to be used later for routevalues
        var paramDic = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        string actionName = call.Method.Name;
        var methodParams = call.Method.GetParameters();

        if (methodParams.Any())
        {
            for (int index = 0; index < methodParams.Length; index++)
            {
                ParameterInfo parameterInfo = methodParams[index];
                Expression expression = call.Arguments[index];
                object objValue;
                var expressionConst = expression as ConstantExpression;
                if(expressionConst!=null)
                {
                    objValue = expressionConst.Value;
                }
                else
                {
                    Expression<Func<object>> expressionConstOther =
                        Expression.Lambda<Func<object>>(
                          Expression.Convert(expression, typeof(object)),
                          new ParameterExpression[0]);
                    objValue = expressionConstOther.Compile()();
                }
                paramDic.Add(parameterInfo.Name, objValue);
            }
        }
        string controllerName = typeof(T).Name;
        if (controllerName.EndsWith("Controller", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            controllerName = controllerName.Remove(controllerName.Length - 10, 10);
        }

        var routeValues = new RouteValueDictionary(paramDic);
        var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(html.ViewContext.RequestContext);
        var url = urlHelper.Action(actionName, controllerName, routeValues);

        const string linkFormat = "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"{0}\"></script>";
        string link = string.Format(linkFormat, url);

        return link;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Usage (where `FundShareholderController` is my controller and `x.JsFile()` is an action method thereon.):

```
<%=Html.Script<FundShareholderController>(x => x.JsFile("CreateInvestorBookingJsFile", 0))%>
```

I hope this makes sense. Let me know if there are any missing details that you need to assist.

BTW - any optimization tips are gladly taken on-board too.

Comment: I don't get it, from your example what parameters do you want intellisensed, and where do the values come from?

Comment: hi iain - the parameters would come from the generic Expression<Action<T>> action. i.e. i might 'point' to an action called GetStuff(int id, string name) and the intellisense should kick in on those parameter names. actually, since writing this, i've managed to get it working, so will update the example at some point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding the XML comments on the method like the following.

```
/// <summary>
/// The summary of my Script Extension method.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">T is the type of Controller</typeparam>
/// <param name="html">The HTML helper.</param>
/// <param name="action">The action Method of the Controller.</param>
/// <returns></returns>
```

After putting the above comments on the extension method, I can see them in the IntelliSense. See the image below.

[image: intellisense]

Comment: hi zain, i gave you the +1, but it doesn't fully answer my requirement, so won't at the moment mark it as definitive answer. but again, thanks for the input ;)

Comment: hi again zain on reflection, this is probably fine for most purposes, so you got yuorself an 'answer' :)